# I have free energy; good idea to mine BTC/LTC?

Tags: mining-profitability, cpu-mining

I don't need to pay for power to my computer. Is it a good idea to mine LTC or BTC on Intel Core Duo processor?

My CPU is 2 x 2.6GHz  (computer woks 24/7)

Answer (score 3):

Mining on both Bitcoin and Litecoin is now dominated by ASICs. Even with Litecoin, you'd only mine at best about US$0.45 worth in a year.

You should have better luck if you can find a cryptocoin based on something besides SHA-256 or scrypt, for which there is no GPU or ASIC mining, such as [Riecoin](http://riecoin.org/) or [Darkcoin](https://www.darkcoin.io/). http://cpucoinlist.com/ lists some more CPU-friendly coins.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these links discuss how to CPU mine profitably.

http://cpucoinlist.com/how-to/how-to-cpu-mine-x11/

or

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=439874.0

But if you don't pay for power... Try to partner up with someone with a good mining rig and divide the profits.